# MS Access SQL receiving no results when joining tables in where clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

i am trying to update a colleague's MS Access application (with vb-code). I am rather experienced in writing SQL queries but i am not able to solve the following problem.

The query i am looking to fix uses a pass-through-query's result and a local MS Access table and joins them togehter in the where-clause (i tried using the normal way with ON but it seems this doesn't work when there is a pass through query involved). I have little experience with joining tables in the where-clause **but is there such a thing that i cant use certain columns (of both tables) in the where-clause when joining tables in the where-clause?** -> When i use a filter criteria such as **columnA <> 'somerandomtext'** (which is always satisfied, just to point out the problem) the query result is empty. When i delete the latter criteria in the where clause, the query returns results (although too many because i cant filter them accordingly).

Furthermore: I checked the pass-through-query, the results are correct. I checked the MS-Access table, the data in the table is correct. Therefore, i think i might be doing something wrong in the query where i join the two mentioned above.

THIS QUERY WORKS AS INTENDED AND RETURNS RESULTS:

```
SELECT t.tr_id, t.ser_num, t.contrgnt_id, t.pos_ekey, t.sernum AS cmdty,             format(t.vol,""##,###,###.00"") AS volume, t.unit_def, t.value_date,
format(t.coup,""##,###,###.00"") AS fixprice,
format(s.calcvarprice,""##,###,###.00"") AS marketprice,
format(s.calcamount,""##,###,###.00"") AS payamount,
format(s.settlevarprice, ""##,###,##0.00"") as settleprice,
format(s.settleamount, ""##,###,##0.00"") as settleamount, s.sync
FROM pms_trans AS t, settledata AS s
WHERE t.tr_id=s.tr_id And t.is_booked='N' And t.value_date>='01.01.2021' And t.value_date<='01.04.2021'
```

THIS QUERY SOMEHOW RETURNS 0 RESULTS:

```
SELECT t.tr_id, t.ser_num, t.contrgnt_id, t.pos_ekey, t.sernum AS cmdty,             format(t.vol,""##,###,###.00"") AS volume, t.unit_def, t.value_date,
format(t.coup,""##,###,###.00"") AS fixprice,
format(s.calcvarprice,""##,###,###.00"") AS marketprice,
format(s.calcamount,""##,###,###.00"") AS payamount,
format(s.settlevarprice, ""##,###,##0.00"") as settleprice,
format(s.settleamount, ""##,###,##0.00"") as settleamount, s.sync
FROM pms_trans AS t, settledata AS s
WHERE t.tr_id=s.tr_id And t.is_booked='N' And t.pos_ekey <> 'BGGS' And t.value_date>='01.01.2021' And t.value_date<='01.04.2021'
```

As mentioned before, i suspect that there are some limitations when joining via where-clause (although i didnt find sufficient information online).

Best Regards and thank you in advance,

Peter

Comment: Missing terminating single quote in `t.value_date>='01.01.2021 And`

Comment: What other values besides 'BGGS' are there in pos_ekey?

Comment: The pos_ekey column contains several names of clients on of them is 'BGGS', another example would be 'KERT'. The column is basically used to filter the clients. But, as i mentioned in my post - even if i enter a ficitonal critera which is always satisfied e.g. <>'fiuhfriu4h3ouf43f' there are no results coming back.

Comment: When you leave out `t.pos_ekey <> 'BGGS'`, do you get values for `t.pos_ekey`? `NULL` is not unequal to `'BGGS'`.

Answer (score 0):

First, apply the correct syntax for the date expressions:

```
WHERE t.tr_id=s.tr_id And t.is_booked='N' And t.pos_ekey <> 'BGGS' And t.value_date >= #2021-01-01# And t.value_date <= #2021-04-01#
```

Next, double-check the values for `pos_ekey`. For example, try to apply the filter, <> 'BGGS', directly on the field in table view.